# Design of my home in ionic Framework

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I hope you can help me with my design, as you see in this image:

[image]

As you can see this messy, icons with the letters of the buttons, on the other hand also does not focus my image, I hope I can help since there is very little of scss in ionic:

[image]

**Code Ionic:**

```
<ion-content padding>
    <img style="align-items: center" src="./../assets/logo.png">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button ion-button icon-start center round full><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>Registrate via Facebook</button>
    <button ion-button icon-start center color="secondary" round full><ion-icon name="person-add"></ion-icon>Servicio Particular</button>
    <button ion-button icon-start center color="dark" round full><ion-icon name="briefcase"></ion-icon>Servicio Corporativo</button>
    <br>
    <p>¿Eres nuevo? <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">REGISTRATE AHORA</a></p>
</ion-content>
```

**code .scss**

```
page-home {
    p {
        text-align-last: center;
    }
}

Examplo:
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: How do you want it to look?

Comment: @robbannn The centered image, the icons of the buttons aligned to the letters and everything to the right, in the image they look very down, I am newbie in ionic: c